# How to get text from table row by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table and at some point I need to get tables text from specific row.

for example here is row:

```
<tr>
<td>
    Tompson Road
    <span style="display: none;">927</span>
</td>
<td>5</td>
</tr>
```

I need to get this text: Tompson Road

I do it this way:

```
    $("#<%= gvFeatList.ClientID %> tr").click(function () {
        var text = $(this).context.innerText;
    });
```

But the text contains:

Tompson Road 927

While I need only - Tompson Road

How do I change this command: `$(this).context.innerText` to get only the text?

Comment: `$(this).contents()[0].wholeText.trim()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also a possible solution to your issue! Since you only want the content in the first `td`, you can use `find()` method and fiter that particular element alone.

```js
$("#test tr").click(function() {
  var text = $(this).find('td:first-child')[0].innerText;
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Tompson Road
      <span style="display: none;">927</span>
    </td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be a name followed by a number you can try this:

`$("#<%= gvFeatList.ClientID %> tr").click(function () {
   var text = $(this).context.innerText.replace(/[1-9]/g, '');
});`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers given, you can also get the `firstElementChild` of the table row and get its `innerText`. See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr").click(function () {
       console.log($(this)[0].firstElementChild.innerText);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>
      Tompson Road
      <span style="display: none;">927</span>
  </td>
  <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```